# How to create a node reference field using the CCK API?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, reference, view, cck

We're currently building a module which automatically create content type, which allow to quickly install content types on any Drupal platform, without having to manually create hundred of content types and fields. In our previous versions, we were manually creating node reference fields and it works great. Now, we want to create it using our module since we have to add those content types and fields on dozen of platforms already under production; creating manually the fields would be a crazy idea. Do we have to use the node reference API? We are close to being able create it but, in VIEWS, the node reference fields do not appears. It seems we missed something. We're trying to check in the CCK php files to understand how the CCK API is used (if we can create it in a form then, for sure, we can code it). Any idea? Which API and functions should we use? I would like to know the proper method on how to do this.

Answer (score -1):

You should use features rather than write code to create content types. Take a site w/ all the types you need, export them to a feature, integrate that with your module, easy as pie!